# Checking channel id with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, laravel

My form is like this , it may has manual social network

[image: social network]

I want to a user enter the id of channel, with `@`.

for example

- @oxbir
- @website

May a user enter with URL, for example https://t.me/oxbir .

how to get validate with JavaScript?

I don't want to enter URL, I want to enter if of channel. `@oxbir`

blade

```
    function showDynamicSocial() {
        let html = '' +
            '@foreach(auth()->user()->socials as $social)\n'+
            '<div class="col-md-6 position-relative">\n' +
            '<i class="fas fa-times text-danger position-absolute"></i>' +
            '<div class="row">\n' +
            '<div class="col-md-4">\n' +
            '<div class="form-group">\n' +
            '<label for="social_id">Social Network</label>\n' +
            '<select id="social_id" name="social_id[]" class="form-control">\n' +
            '@foreach($socials as $socialData)\n'+
            '<option value="{{ $socialData->id }}" {{ $socialData->id == $social->id ? 'selected' : ''}}>\n'+
            '{{ $socialData->name }}\n' +
            '</option>\n' +
            '@endforeach\n' +
            '</select>\n' +
            '</div>\n' +
            '</div>\n' +
            '<div class="col-md-8">\n' +
            '<div class="form-group">\n' +
            '<label for="link">Profile ID</label>\n' +
            '<input id="link" value="{{ $social->pivot->link }}" name="link[]" class="form-control">\n' +
            '</div>\n' +
            '</div>\n' +
            '</div>\n' +
            '</div>\n ' +
            '@endforeach';
        $('#showSocial').append(html);
    }
```

javascript

```
$('div .btn-next').on('click', function() {
    var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
    var next_step = true;
    var current_active_step = $(this).parents('div').find('.form-wizard.active');
    var progress_line = $(this).parents('div').find('.progress-line');
    if( next_step ) {
        parent_fieldset.fadeOut(400, function() {
            current_active_step.removeClass('active').addClass('activated').next().addClass('active');
            bar_progress(progress_line, 'right');
            $(this).next().fadeIn();
            scroll_to_class( $('.wizards'), 20 );
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: ```first_name``` is the username?

Comment: you can validate username like this if @ is not added : ```function validUserName(name){return name.startsWith("@")?name: "@"+name;}```

Comment: May a user enter with URL, for example https://t.me/oxbir .

Comment: I don't want users to add addresses.

Comment: ```function validUserName(name){
var index = name.lastIndexOf("/");
name = name.substr(index>=0?index+1: 0)
return name.startsWith("@")?name: "@"+name;
}```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225065/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-mahmoud-khosravi).